# Tkinter window not opening in pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am eriting code in pycharm with tkinter but the window is not opening. May someone assist?
`

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Do not press this button! >:-(", width=40)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

`

i tried checking my script for bugs but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Pycharm, but with tkinter library and how to use it.

You are missing 2 important stuff:

- Button is in ttk.py file inside tkinter library: `from tkinter import ttk`
- Execute the whole script with `mainloop`

Try this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk  # Import ttk file from tkinter library


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Coolest title ever written")

button = ttk.Button(window, text="Do not press this button! >:-(", width=40)  # Use Button from the import ttk file
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()  # Execute the whole script
```